# What does graph argument in tf.Session() do?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am having trouble understanding the graph argument in the `tf.Session()`. I tried looking up at the TensorFlow website :[link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session) but couldn't understand much.

I am trying to find out the different between `tf.Session()` and `tf.Session(graph=some_graph_inserted_here)`.

## Question Context

#### Code A (Not Working):

```
def predict():
    with tf.name_scope("predict"):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")
            saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/testing")
            loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            output_ = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('loss/network/output_layer/BiasAdd:0')
            _x = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
            print sess.run(output_, feed_dict={_x: np.array([12003]).reshape([-1, 1])})
```

This code gives the following error: `ValueError: cannot add op with name hidden_layer1/kernel/Adam as that name is already used` when trying to load the graph at `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")`

#### Code B (Working):

```
def predict():
    with tf.name_scope("predict"):
        loaded_graph = tf.Graph()
        with tf.Session(graph=loaded_graph) as sess:
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")
            saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/testing")
            output_ = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('loss/network/output_layer/BiasAdd:0')
            _x = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
            print sess.run(output_, feed_dict={_x: np.array([12003]).reshape([-1, 1])})
```

The codes does not work if I replace `loaded_graph = tf.Graph()` with `loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()`. Why?

Full Code if it helps:
 (https://gist.github.com/duemaster/f8cf05c0923ebabae476b83e895619ab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The TensorFlow `Graph` is an object which contains your various `tf.Tensor` and `tf.Operation`.

When you create these tensors (e.g. using `tf.Variable` or `tf.constant`) or operations (e.g. `tf.matmul`), they will be added to the default graph (look at the `graph` member of these object to get the graph they belong to).  If you haven't specified anything, it will be the graph you get when calling the `tf.get_default_graph` method.

But you could also work with multiple graphes using a context manager:

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    [your code]
```

Suppose you created several graphes in your code, you then need to put the graph you and to run as an argument of the `tf.Session` method to specify TensorFlow which one to run.

In Code A, you

- work with the default graph,
- try to import the meta graph into it (which fails because it already contains some of the nodes) and,
- would restore the model into it,

while in Code B, you

- create a fresh new graph,
- import the meta graph into it (which succeeds because it's an empty graph) and
- restore it.

### Useful link:

[`tf.Graph` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph)

### Edit:

This piece of code makes the Code A work (I reset the default graph to a fresh one, and I removed the predict `name_scope`).

```
def predict():
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")
        saver.restore(sess, "saved_models/testing")
        loaded_graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        output_ = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('loss/network/output_layer/BiasAdd:0')
        _x = loaded_graph.get_tensor_by_name('x:0')
        print(sess.run(output_, feed_dict={_x: np.array([12003]).reshape([-1, 1])}))
```

Comment: I tried adding a `tf.reset_default_graph()` before `with tf.name_scope("predict"):` and did not pass any graph to tf.Session(). An error appeared saying a certain tensor was not found. So am I right to say that `tf.train.import_meta_graph()` only add on to graphes, and I need a graph to be set as default or passed in to tf.Session() so as to provide a "canvas" for the import function to "draw" on?

Comment: This is because you put yourself in the `name_scope` predict and it confuses TensorFlow (remember that the name scope is part of the name of the `Tensor`s and `Operation`s).   The simplest would be to just remove this predict `name_scope`. It would be also more consistent: you probably don't want to create a new predict `Graph`, you want to use an existing `Graph` and use it to make predictions. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In Tensorflow, you are constructing graphs. By default, Tensorflow creates a default (sorry for tautology) graph (which you could access using `tf.get_default_graph()`). By default, any new `Session` object uses this default graph.

In your case, you already have a graph (which is a default one), and you also saved exactly this graph into meta file. Then, you are trying to recover this graph using `tf.train.import_meta_graph()`. However, since your session uses a default graph, and you are trying to recover an identical one, you are encountering an error since this operation is trying to duplicate the nodes, which is forbidden.

When you explicitly create a new graph object by calling `tf.Graph()` and create a `Session` object using this graph (but not the default one) everything is fine since the nodes are created in another graph.

Answer (score 1):

The function `tf.train.import_meta_graph("saved_models/testing.meta")` add all the nodes from the `meta` file to the `current graph`. In the first code, the `current graph` is the `default_graph` which already has the ops defined, so the error. In the second case, you are loading the nodes to a new graph and so it works fine!.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Session you're placing a graph into a specified device.

If no graph is specified, the Session constructor tries to build a graph using the default one (that you can get using `tf.get_default_graph`).

Your code A doesn't work because in the current session already exists a graph and that graph already contains the same exact node you're trying to import.

Your code B works because you're placing into the Session a new empyt graph (created with `tf.Graph()`): when you import the graph definition there's no collision among the existing nodes in the current session (that are 0, because the graph is empty) and the ones you're importing